# Form selector not work working on dynamic markup

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I execute the following code, it behaves like I expect (logs the contents of the `DIV` element):

```
var html = '<form action="/" method="get" name="myform"><div>123</div></form>';
console.log($('div', html));
```

What I can't understand is why the following code does NOT work:

```
var html = '<form action="/" method="get" name="myform"><div>123</div></form>';
console.log($('form', html));
```

They seem the same, so why does the `DIV` selector work when the `FORM` selector does not?

Comment: Do you understand how the `$('div', html)` syntax works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var html = '<form action="/" method="get" name="myform"><div>123</div></form>';
console.log($(html).html());
```

as the form is the root element of `html`, `$(html)` will already return you the desired JQuery Object.
So if you try to select a form tag Jquery tries to find another form-tag within your form, which - of course - does not exist.

Comment: .html() will return you the innerHTML of the form. You could also use something like addClass(...) and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply, the second example doesn't work because there is no  element to find *within the context of* the string, whereas in the first example, there *is* a div that exists within the context of the string.

In jQuery, the format `$('div', html)` means find the div element within the context of the `html` variable. It's equivalent to `$(html).find('div')`. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#expressioncontext

> **Selector Context**
>   By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting
>   at the document root. However, an alternate context can be given for
>   the search by using the optional second parameter to the $() function.
>   For example, to do a search within an event handler, the search can be
>   restricted like so:
>
> ```
> $( "div.foo" ).click(function() {
>   $( "span", this ).addClass( "bar" );
> });
> ```
>
> When the search for the span selector is restricted to the context of
>   this, only spans within the clicked element will get the additional
>   class.
>
> Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method,
>   so  `$( "span", this )` is equivalent to `$( this ).find( "span" )`.

Since your second example has no form *within* the string's content (only a div is within it), it finds no match.

Comment: That's I'm talking about :)

Answer (score 0):

For the selector, the second parameter should be a jQuery or DOM object. If you provide a string, it will search for the content of the string. To make it work, you should make the html variable to be an object by:

```
var html = $('<form action="/" method="get" name="myform"><div>123</div></form>');
console.log($('div', html));
```

Then if you want, you can add it to your page by:

```
$('body').add(html);
```

It's also a good idea to use a $ for jQuery object variables:

```
var $html = $('<form action="/" method="get" name="myform"><div>123</div></form>');
```

So you can easily know that this is a jQuery object already, and you don't have to call for ex. $(html).show() every time you want to do something with it, you can simply call $html.show();

Comment: It doesn't work for `$('form', html)`. You've actually written pretty much the same code (it works in same way like the original one).

Answer (score 0):

`$('form', html)` works as `$(html).find('form')`. `.find()` doesn't look at original element, only at its children, so `form` can't be found.

You can use some workaround for it, like this one:

```
var html = '<form action="/" method="get" name="myform"><div>123</div></form>';
console.log($('form', '<div>' + html + '</div>'));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bsnkp5vm/).